# Can someone explain to me how a closure works? (Swift iOS)

Tags: swift

I am looking for a high level explaination of what happens under the hood. How do they work, how are they defined, how are they called, what happens when they are called, are the asynchronous?

Thanks!

Comment: http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter5/closures.aspx (I know it's C# but it explains the overall concept very well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously there are the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html), which is a good starting point.  At a high level, I think of them as portable functions, which can capture other objects from the current context.  I don't believe they are asynchronous or synchronous, because they don't determine when or how they run.

They do lend themselves to asynchronous patterns though, and I think they are most often used in an asynchronous way - because they allow you to package up a particular behavior and pass that along to something else.  A perfect example of this being completion handlers in the url session task methods.  Your completion handler in this case, is just a closure that lets you say now what you want the task to do when it completes.

Comment: Re "they are most often used in an asynchronous way". One could conceivably argue this position with Objective-C blocks (though enumeration, sorting, predicates, and the like, are typical counter-examples), but with functional programming in Swift, this position is even more tenuous. Bottom line, to your earlier point, closures are neither inherently asynchronous nor synchronous. It just depends upon how they're used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have read the documents but as I am new it sometimes is hard to grasp the meaning behind the words. Thank you